SharePoint Image columns(thumbnail) behaving differently
My SharePoint Image columns(thumbnail) are behaving differently. It was previously saving the items in the below format:
'{"type":"thumbnail","fileName":"test.jpg","nativeFile":{},"fieldName":"ProfilePicture","serverUrl":"https://mytest.sharepoint.com","fieldId":"id","serverRelativeUrl":"/sites/SIteName/SiteAssets/Lists/ListID/image.jpg","id":"ID"}'

But now it is returning data in the below format:
"{\"fileName\":\"Reserved_ImageAttachment_[14]_[ProfilePicture][7]_[content][2]_[10].jpg\"}"

what could be the reason?
All the existing items are returning the data in old proper formats, but uploading a new image is returning the data in the improper format.
Please help

This is happening because Microsoft changed behavior of "Image" column type earlier this year (or last year).
With those updates to SharePoint Online and Microsoft Lists, if the Attachments option is Enabled in your SharePoint list, images will be stored in SAME SharePoint list (attachments section) instead of storing those in Site Assets library.
Also, when SharePoint is storing images in attachments section of same list, it does not populate "serverRelativeUrl" attribute image format properly.
You can read more details about this at:

SharePoint Online: All you need to know about New Image column type
Images no longer showing in SharePoint card gallery view


If you are not going to utilize Attachments feature for your SharePoint list to upload any documents, you can disable it from list settings:

Go to your SharePoint list
Click on Settings (gear) icon from top right corner
Select List settings
Select Advanced Settings from List settings page
Set Attachments (Attachments to list items are) to "Disabled" --> Please do this carefully because it will delete all attachments from selected SharePoint list (if there are any).
Click OK button at the bottom of page to save changes


Thanks a lot for your reply and your site helped a lot in understanding the issue. But may I know if there's any easy way to retrieve the images incase of lists with attachments?

Where do you want to retrieve those exactly? In JSON formatting OR using SharePoint REST API or in Power Apps or in Power Automate or somewhere else?

I need to fetch the items along with the image column from the list using SharePoint REST API and to display the results.

Fetching list items along with it's attachments using single API call might not be possible using SharePoint REST API.

Agree with Genesh Sanap. I am checking the status of this case. Please let us know if you would like further assistance.
If you have any update about this issue, please feel free to post back.
